# Interpretation of orthogonal impulse response

Tags: var

I have some problems with understanding the result of my orthogonal impulse response plot. 
[image]

```
oir <- irf(VARd, impulse = "LogEPU", response = "GDPDelta",
           n.ahead = 10, ortho = TRUE, runs = 100, ci=0.9)
```

I understand most of the graph. But I do not know how to interpret the negative value in t=0. Does that mean that there is a contemporaneous downmovement of my response variable when a shock to my impulse variable occurs?